# Can't get User Mode Linux slirp networking to work

Tags: linux, networking, uml

I am trying to use UML with the Slirp networking backend (I am aware of the restrictions). This is my current attempt:

```
./vmlinux init=/bin/ash eth0=slirp
```

With root_fs being an alpine image. Then, I use this commands to activate the connection:

```
# ifconfig eth0 10.2.0.15 up #Prints "SLiRP Ready" message
# route add default dev eth0
```

However, when I then try to resolve a hostname:

```
# nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

What may I be doing wrong? I am on Debian Sid, all packages updated.

Comment: Does `curl -v https://1.1.1.1` make a connection and grab a webpage? On Debian bullseye, this with a custom 6.1 compiled UML kernel the works for me.

Comment: Nope, it does not. Same thing, timeout.